# A $t$-transitive permutation group of degree $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose we have a $t$-transitive permutation group $G$ of degree $n$, where $t$ is greater or equal to $2$.

Then why does this not imply that $G = S_n$?

As since $G$ acts $2$-transitively then $G$ must contain all transpositions, and therefore in fact be $S_n$.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line "since $G$ acts $2$-transitively it must contain all transpositions" is wrong. $G$ being $2$-transitive means that for every $a,b,a',b'\in X$ (the set acted on by $G$) we have some $g\in G$ s.t. $ga=a', gb=b'$. In order for $g$ to be a transposition, it would additionally have to fix every other element of $X$, but this need not be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Consider also this.

A finite group which is $2$-transitive on a set $X$ with $n$ elements must have order divisible by $n (n-1)$.

Now for a prime $p$ the group of all maps $x \mapsto a x + b$, for $a \in \mathbf{F}_{p}^{*}$ and $b  \in \mathbf{F}_{p}$ acts $2$-transitively on $\mathbf{F}_{p}$, and has order exactly $p (p-1)$, that is, as small as possible.

Comment: Do you know any examples of a primitive subgroup of $ S_n $ which has order divisible by $ n(n-1) $ but is not 2 transitive?

Comment: oh wow this is a great example. Could you say a little more about why $ S_{k} $ is primitive but not $ 2 $-transitive? Also would it make more sense for me to just post this as a question and you could answer it?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira, if you wish to make it into a post, I'll be glad to post an answer. As to your question, the one-point stabiliser in the action of $S_{k}$ on the set of two-elements subsets is isomorphic to $S_{2} \times S_{k-2}$. It is a general fact that if $a \ne b$ are both greater than $1$, then $S_{a} \times S_{b}$ is maximal in $S_{a+b}$. I have the simple proof written up in some notes of mine, but they are in Italian. Still, it's brief, so I might translate it for the answer. Of course somebody else might come up with a better answer than mine, but that's perfectly ok.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira, there was a silly mistake in my previous comment. Here's a corrected version. This is probably a rather artificial example, and does not hold for all $n$ Consider the symmetric group $S_k$ acting naturally on the set $\Omega$ of two-elements subsets of $\{1,2,…,k\}$, for $k \ge 5$. Clearly $\Omega$ has order $n=k(k−1)/2$. As a subgroup of $S_n$, we have that $S_k$ is primitive, but not $2$-transitive. Direct computations show that the order $k!$ of $S_k$ is divisible by $n(n−1)$ for $k=7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, \dots$

Answer (score 1):

"As since G acts 2 transitively then G must contain all transpositions" -this is not true.

"Then why does this not imply that $G = S_n$?" - E.g., $A_n (n\ge 3)$ is $(n-2)$-transitive.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is 2-transitive, then for all ordered pairs $(i,j),(k,\ell)$, there is an element $g \in G$ such that $g$ takes $i$ to $k$ and $j$ to $\ell$.  Thus, $g$ would have the cycle decomposition $g=(i,k,\ldots,j,\ell,\ldots) \cdots$ or $g=(i,k,\ldots)(j,\ell,\ldots) \cdots$.  Observe that this $g$ is not a transposition, and so $G$ need not contain any transpositions at all.   On the other hand, the following assertion is true: If $G$ is 2-transitive and contains at least one transposition, then it contains all transpositions and hence equals $S_n$.  Proof: if $G$ is 2-transitive and contains  $(i,j)$, then for any other transposition $(k,\ell)$, there is some $g \in G$ such that conjugation by $g$ gives $g^{-1}(i,j)g = (k,\ell)$, whence $G$ contains $(k,\ell)$ also; since $G$ contains all transpositions, it equals $S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the alternating group $A_n$. It is $(n-2)$-transitive and does not contain any transposition.